# Segmented Control inside of Scroll View

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a really long segmented controller to let users choose between many options. How can I go about getting it inside of a Scroll View?

I've tried dragging and dropping it but it doesn't let me scroll it.

Comment: Segmented controls shouldn't be that long; I would recommend using a different control for those cases -- such as a pop-over menu.

Comment: I second that, @QwertyBob, Especially with the UI changes in iOS7, I was just testing this and it is aggravatingly difficult to get my finger on the UISegmentedControl just right to get it to scroll.

Comment: Really? It wouldn't scroll?

Comment: See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496604/weird-interface-bug-uiscrollview-in-uitabbarcontroller-reproducible-by-others

Comment: You could have a button opening up a screen offering a vertical list of options if you have many options.  (Like the system's listing languages in "General > International > Language").  The button would bare the name of the current selection.

Comment: I got this implemented and it's different but it seems to work pretty well. I don't want to take the user to a new page because they are editing what information they want graphed on this page

Comment: @Centree in iOS7 it scrolls, but the UISegmentedControl is MUCH shorter than the ones in iOS6--, its about 28 pixels tall excluding the border... which is difficult (for me and my awkward fingers) to hold just right to scroll.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a segmented control in a scroll view by this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    journals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 49, 320, 29)];
    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 29);

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height -1);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

    [scrollView addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [self fillJournals];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Here's a post on how to create a segmented control inside a scroll view

http://penningthoughtsandmemoirs.com/2013/12/16/sliding-segmented-control/

Download the source code from :

https://github.com/sahilriaz1110/SlidingSegmentedControl

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the content size of the `UIScrollView`, otherwise it won't scroll.

```
myScrollView.contentSize = mySegmentedControl.frame.size;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of suggesting how to put the segmented control in a scrollview (see the other answers listed) I'm going to suggest a different approach altogether:  change UI element.

If you had a couple (two to three) mutually exclusive options on a desktop application, you could use radio buttons and it would make sense;  but if you had ten and above options, throwing these radio button in a scrollview would not be the best choice.  A better/cleaner user interface would make use of a drop-down menu.

That was for a desktop application.. but the UI principles for mobile OSes are the same.  A segment control should have few options (maybe five tops).  Any more than that and you should use a different UI element.

Imagine if the iPhone, when selecting a language, offered every language in a segmented control.  No!  Instead, when choosing a language, you're shown a list to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using autolayout?  If so then you will need to set the scrollView's content size from within viewDidLayoutSubviews.  Like:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [scrollView setContentSize:[segControl frame].size];
}
```

If you aren't using autolayout then you can just do it in `-(void)viewDidLoad` like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [scrollView setContentSize:[segControl frame].size];
}
```

**EDIT** You may also want to make the scrollview contentSize slightly smaller than your segmented control so there is no give in the vertical direction:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([segControl frame].size.width, [segControl frame].size.height-1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `UISegmentedControl` width is `640`, use:

```
[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([segControl frame].size.width, 0)];
```

Using this line will make it scroll horizontally to choose more option on `UISegmentedControl`.

Answer (score -1):

In UIBuilder you can add ScrollView that goes inside the ViewController and fill it with your segmented control that it's bigger than the screen.

[image: Segmented Control Storyboard]
[image: Segmented Control UI Properties]